# Test an Nginx webapp in Android with faked domain

Tags: nginx

I am migrating a webapp to AWS EC2 with Nginx.

Thing is I must edit /etc/hosts, so I can test that.

But now, I have an Android app that I need to test, how can I make it work to connect the new url?

Is there a way to connect temp url? Is there a non root way to change internal /etc/hosts in Android???

How should I test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fake a DNS entry in the next DNS Server - your router.

If you connect the device via Wireless-LAN to your router, it gets the false entry before any other entries and will use your test IP.

Update:

found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file), which should solve your problem without a DNS.

Comment: can you detail how to do it? I may not have access to DNS Server, but it is worth to try

Comment: yep! Tx, just need to root the device... :(